# magento turpentine cart sidebar

Tags: magento, varnish

I've been using turpentine as varnish cache on a startup e-commerce site and I am very satisfied with the performance. I am using magento 1.7.0.2 with turpentine 0.5.4.

However, I have a problem with the sidebar cart. It gets cached and if I add products to my cart, when I come back to a cached page it still says 0 products.

I have "cart_sidebar" on private in my turpentine_esi.xml, and I have block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" in my checkout.xml (although it's in my theme, not in the base folder). I have saved and applied varnish config multiple times. I have read the similar issues, with no success in resolving this so far. You can test the problem here: http://www.easyfarm.ro

Any help would be really, really much appreciated since I have been struggling with this for some time. At first I thought it was from my em_ajaxcart module, but I disabled it and the problem is still there.

Comment: did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: yes, just set access on private, as highlighted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to stop caching the cart sidebar , I added the following code to my theme's checkout.xml

```
<block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" as="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml">
    <action method="setEsiOptions">
        <params>
            <method>ajax</method>
            <access>private</access>
        </params>
    </action>
</block>
```

Comment: That did the trick to remove text '**ESI processing not enabled**' - https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/issues/1329